# Скрывать FAB при скролле в WebView - Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Всем доброго времени суток. Хотелось бы узнать, как можно скрывать виджеты (не обязательно FAB) при скролле в WebView (скролл вниз - скрыть, скролл - вверх показать). Думал использовать `GestureDetector`, но, по моему, это не правильно и наверняка есть встроенный "инструмент" для реализации этого. Так, например, в WebView на Android это можно сделать используя `setOnScrollChangeListener` и через него настроить поведение того же FAB по осям X и Y (в моём случае только по оси Y).

Answer (score 0):

Я это делал так:

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      print("This one doesn't print");
    },
    child: Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          WebView(
            initialUrl:
                'example.com',
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
              _controller.complete(webViewController);
            },
            gestureRecognizers: Set()
              ..add(
                  Factory<TapGestureRecognizer>(() => TapGestureRecognizer()
                    ..onTapDown = (tap) {
                      //тут прячем все что пожелаем
                    })),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
```